# How to "roll-up"/aggregate rows from a badly designed table with SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access

So I'm working with this badly designed table, but it's from another department and I need the data so I have no control over it. How can I get in a proper state? I'm working with MS Access so unfortunately I don't have access to "advanced" SQL functions like partition by, or row_number, etc.

This is the bad table:

| KeyID | PA | QL | RuleName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | X |  | YYY |
| 1111 |  | X | ZZZ |
| 1111 |  | X | OOO |

I want my final table to look like this:

| KeyID | PA | QL | RuleNamePA | RuleNameQL | RuleNameQL2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | X | X | YYY | ZZZ | OOO |

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your desired output is not really a 'proper state' any more than the original data structure is - it's worse. Since the PA and QL fields appear to be Yes/No type and mutually exclusive, a properly normalized table would be like:

| ID | KeyID | Cat | RuleName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1111 | PA | yyy |
| 2 | 1111 | QL | zzz |
| 3 | 1111 | QL | ooo |

That structure can be achieved with:

`SELECT ID, KeyID, IIf(PA, "PA", "QL") AS Cat, RuleName FROM Table2;`

Then that query can be used like a table in subsequent queries such as a CROSSTAB:

```
TRANSFORM First(RuleName) AS FirstOfRuleName
SELECT KeyID
FROM Query1
GROUP BY KeyID
PIVOT "RuleName" & [Cat] & DCount("*","Query1","Cat='" & [Cat] & "' AND ID<" & [ID])+1;
```

If there is no unique identifier ID field, change the DCount to:
`DCount("*","Query1","Cat='" & [Cat] & "' AND KeyID & Cat & RuleName<'" & [KeyID] & [Cat] & [RuleName] & "'")+1`

Here is a version that does not use Query1 and will provide the PA and QL fields which really don't seem necessary. Again, adjust the DCount if there is no ID field.

```
TRANSFORM First(RuleName) AS FirstOfRuleName
SELECT Table1.KeyID, Max(Abs([PA])) AS P, Max(Abs([QL])) AS Q
FROM Table1
GROUP BY KeyID
PIVOT "RuleName" & IIf([PA],"PA","QL") & DCount("*","Table1","IIf([PA],'PA','QL')='" & IIf([PA],"PA","QL") & "' AND ID<" & [ID])+1;
```

Comment: Oh sorry I just updated my example because it wasn't correct. KeyID can be more than 2 records.

Comment: See revised answer.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer does work and I sued it for a while, but with large amounts of data it takes too long to process. So I went back to the drawing board and spent time normalizing my initial data before getting it in Access and now everything is easier.